# How can I change the font color of Mission Control?

Tags: font, mission-control, color

[image]

macOS Ventura 13.6, M1 macbook air.

For example, my VSCode has many workspaces (windows), and when I use Mission Control I need the titles below the windows to recognize them; but the white font color makes it so hard to read the titles, and I don't want to change my desktop picture. Are there any ways to change the font color of Mission Control?

Comment: Mission Control doesn't do anything with the fonts, it just shows the application windows.

Comment: @red_menace - It shows the window name below each window, always in white - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU9An.jpg

Comment: Thanks. It seems there's nothing for it.